# After loading website it goes to a specific section without hash

Tags: html, css, blogger

Hello I use google blogspot. Recently I added this code in my blogger widget. But after implement this code my website automatically goes to this section. I want that it will stay on header after loading without hash tag. How can I do that? It it possible with html?
That code is:

```css
.dom-flex {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 36%;
}

.main-domain {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 584px;
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.input {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.input input,
.input button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  line-height: inherit;
  font: inherit;
}

.input input {
  background-color: #ffa0d6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  outline: none;
}

.input button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #ff65bd 50%, #ff2483 50%);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.results {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.domain {
  display: table;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.domain-taken {
  background-color: #d23d47;
  color: #fff;
}

.domain-free {
  background: #07c277;
  color: #fff;
}

.domain-free:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.domain-taken:before {
  content: '\f00d';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.domain:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

.domain:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.bkash {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff65bd 50%, #ff2483 50%);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-domain'>
  <h3>Buy Domain with<span class="bkash"> Bkash</span></h3>
  <form class="input" id="input">
    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus="" id="name" name="name" type="text" />
    <button>Check</button>
  </form>
  <div class="results" id="results">
    <a class="domain" href="#" id="domain">helloworld.com</a>
    <a class="domain" href="#" id="domain">helloworld.com</a>
  </div>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. There is nothing in the snippet that will "go" anywhere. If you load the page with a URL that ends with #results, the browser will load the page and move to the element with id="results"

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Don’t link to #results

Comment: Hey @mplungjan I replace # with "javascript:void(0)" but it can't solved.

Comment: I meant the link to the page not the link on the page